# Python If statement and logical operator issue

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to create a small python program to emulate rolling a single die. My problem arises in that I want the program to accept both upper and lower-case 'Y' to trigger a re-roll. My program works when I accept either upper or lower case y but when I try to change the line

```
if usr == 'Y'
```

to

```
if usr == 'Y' or 'y'
```

creates a problem where it never enters the else statement, making the program never terminate.

```
import random

def DiceRoll():
 number = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
 print("Dice Roll: ", number)
 AskUser()
 return

def AskUser():
 usr = input("Roll Again? (Y/N) \n")
 if usr == 'Y':
     DiceRoll()
 else :
     print("Thank you for playing!")
return

DiceRoll()
```

Comment: try `if usr in ('Y', 'y')`, or `if usr.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: just use usr = usr.lower() and only check for lowercase y

Comment: I changed it to  `if usr in ('Y','y'):`  and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148815/discussion-on-question-by-zac-python-if-statement-and-logical-operator-issue).

Answer (score 1):

You must do

```
if usr == 'Y' or usr == 'y'.
```

It is currently evaluating the statement 'y' as its own condition, and in this case 'y' always evaluates to true.